# Switch Statement: Applying Multiple Arguments in One Output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can apply two different conditions to one output in a switch statement. For example, I have a function to style a string depending on what arguments that 2nd parameter gets. The first and second output is okay since it only has one argument for styling but the third output does. I cannot find a way to apply both uppercase and reversed styling to a string. I've tried to loop a switch statement. I'd like to know if there are any good solutions for this.

```js
function caseStyle(string, style) {
  function toUpper(string) {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    return string;
  }

  function toReversed(string) {
    string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    return string;
  }

  switch (style) {
    case "upper":
      string = toUpper(string);
      break;
    case "reversed":
      string = toReversed(string);
      break;
  }
  return string;
}

console.log(caseStyle("hello", "upper")); //output: HELLO
console.log(caseStyle("hello", "reversed")); //output: olleh
console.log(caseStyle("hello", ["upper", "reversed"])); // expected output: OLLEH
```

Comment: you need to introduce new case. 
`case "reversedUpper": return toUpper(toReversed(string))`

Comment: you'd need to check if `style` is an array, and handle accordingly

Comment: check if style is an array. if not make it a single element array like `style = [style]` and then do a for loop on the style array that tests each element. This will allow you to have as many styles as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd need to check if `style` is an array, and handle accordingly

Or, force it to be an Array `style = [style].flat()` and then iterate that array

The `.flat()` will flatten the array in the case when an array is passed in

as follows

```js
function caseStyle(string, style) {
  style = [style].flat();
  function toUpper(string) {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    return string;
  }

  function toReversed(string) {
    string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    return string;
  }
  style.forEach(style => {
    switch (style) {
      case "upper":
        string = toUpper(string);
        break;
      case "reversed":
        string = toReversed(string);
        break;
    }
  });
  return string;
}

console.log(caseStyle("hello", "upper")); //output: HELLO
console.log(caseStyle("hello", "reversed")); //output: olleh
console.log(caseStyle("hello", ["upper", "reversed"])); // expected output: OLLEH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch (true)` in the following way:

```js
function caseStyle(string, style) {
      function toUpper(string) {
        string = string.toUpperCase();
        return string;
      }

  function toReversed(string) {
    string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    return string;
  }

  switch (true) {
    case style === "upper":
      string = toUpper(string);
      break;
    case style === "reversed":
      string = toReversed(string);
      break;
    case style.includes("upper") && style.includes("reversed"):
      string = toUpper(toReversed(string))
      break;
    default:
       break;
  }
  return string;
}

console.log(caseStyle("hello", "upper"));//output: HELLO
console.log(caseStyle("hello", "reversed"));//output: olleh
console.log(caseStyle("hello", ["upper", "reversed"]));// expected output: OLLEH
```

Comment: sure, but what if you want to add more "functions" ... then your case statements will become unwieldy

Comment: This is not what you asked for

Comment: I didn't ask for anything. Was pointing out a potential flaw in your solution. No big deal, just pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Besides some to-the-point answers in here...
I'd present a different approach:

- Move the inner functions `toUpper` and `toReversed` outside of your `caseStyle` function. There's no need to have them in there
- Use Arrow Functions and implicit return instead of doing twice(!) `str = str...` in the method functions and again in the switch case
- Group your functions into an Object called `methods` - and name your functions exactly like their string names-references
- Instead of a switch-case, use **[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**
- Instead of wrapping your String/or/Array logic into an `if` statement, always force the second array (btw, rename it to `styles`, plural) to always be an Array by converting the string into Array. Even more, by using `.split(/\W+/)` (split by one or more non-word characters) you can now also pass a string like `"upper,reversed"`
- Thanks to this logic you're decoupling your `methods` and you can add more at any point in time, an you can use in the future the expected methods (transformation) names you have available like i.e: `caseStyle("hello", ["snake", "capitalize", "reverse"])` or more.

```js
const methods = {
  upper: str => str.toUpperCase(),
  reversed: str => [...str].reverse().join(""),
};

const caseStyle = (str, styles) => {
  if (typeof styles === "string") styles = styles.split(/\W+/);
  return styles.reduce((acc, style) => methods[style](acc), str);
};

console.log(caseStyle("hello", "upper")); //output: HELLO
console.log(caseStyle("hello", "reversed")); //output: olleh
console.log(caseStyle("hello", ["upper", "reversed"])); // expected output: OLLEH
console.log(caseStyle("stack", "reversed upper")); // expected output: KCATS
```

As you can notice from the above, I've used the **preferred** string Spread syntax `[...str]` to convert a String to Array. One might run into problems when using `.split("")` on a string that uses more than one code point to represent a glyph, like i.e: Emoji:

### Issue when using `.split("")`

```js
console.log("ab".split(""))
```

will give: `["a","b","�","�","�","�"]`

### Better string split: using Spread syntax:

```js
console.log([..."ab"])
```

as you can see the emojis are correctly split and preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run a simple for-of-loop? You'll also need to check if the input isn't an array, then turn it into an array if it isn't already.

```js
function caseStyle(string, styles) {
  function toUpper(string) {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    return string;
  }

  function toReversed(string) {
    string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    return string;
  }
  
  if (!(styles instanceof Array)) styles = [styles];
  for (const style of styles) {
    switch (style) {
      case "upper":
        string = toUpper(string);
        break;
      case "reversed":
        string = toReversed(string);
        break;
    }
  }
  return string;
}

console.log(caseStyle("hello", "upper")); //output: HELLO
console.log(caseStyle("hello", "reversed")); //output: olleh
console.log(caseStyle("hello", ["upper", "reversed"])); // expected output: OLLEH
```

Comment: Did you run the code?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I had a small bug. I've fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: there's also `Array.isArray` function - but I like my solution better :p but this illustrates that there's many ways to do simple things in javascript